# How do i create a rotation matrix given a direction vector?

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to rotate an object to face the direction it is moving in. We want it to face the normalized velocity vector.. help... pls...

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. Do you want to rotate along the great circle between the two points, or do you want to preserve some notion of "up" for the object?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `Matrix.CreateLookAt` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.createlookat.aspx))?

```
// Matrix.CreateLookAt(eyeLocation, lookAt, upVector); 
Matrix.CreateLookAt(currentPosition, currentPosition + velocity, Vector.Up);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, our object is on the x,y plane and we want to rotate about z. I tried your suggestion but it is swinging around the x-axis as if it is applying translation before rotation.

Comment: If you have a 2D plane you might prefer `Vector3.Backward`. And if it seems that it's applying translation before rotation, why not just switch the ordering of the matrices? The ordering should be `RotateMatrix*TranslateMatrix*Vector`. `A*B != B*A` if you use matrices.

Comment: The only matrix i am applying is from CreateLookAt, and it seems it is applying some sort of translation as well as rotation..